# Will quick links to sub sections look like keyword stuffing to search engines?

Tags: seo, anchor, keyword-stuffing

I have a query regarding the use of quick links (table of contents) for lengthy posts. On my website, my posts are in the range of 2000 to 5000 words. I break my post into subsections. Each subsection will have an `h2` heading followed by content.

To help readers navigate quickly between the subsections, I am thinking of adding the list of subsection "headers" in the form of "table of contents". These are essentially internal links to `h2` headings.

To clarify further, the structure of the post will be:

```
**H1: Main Heading Of The Post**

 **Table of Contents:**

  Section A  (internal link to *"H2: Section A"* )

  Section B  (internal link to *"H2: Section B"* )
  ....

**H2: Section A**

Content

**H2: Section B**

Content
... and so on
```

Does repeating the headings in the table of contents will look like keyword stuffing? If yes, is there a better way to accomplish my objective?

Comment: No. You should be fine. Just be natural and do what is right for your users. Do not think in terms of keywords. The whole notion of keywords is a SEO myth. This simply is not how search works. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

It's not keyword stuffing to have the same combination of words on a page if that combination is helpful to the user. In your case, the table of contents and the h2 tag duplication is likely very helpful to the users.

Wikipedia uses the exact model that you are using, and they rank amazingly. Their table of contents also has

```
<a href="#anatomy">Anatomy</a> 

<h3><div id="#anatomy">Anatomy</div></h3>
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Anatomy

Using proper anchor text, proper id=text, and proper text within the h3 tag really helps Google understand their page and it also is really useful for the visitor.

A lot of alternative wikis use this exact same format, and many of them rank very highly.

If your articles are that long, a table of contents like you're thinking about using is probably very beneficial for your site. And longer articles usually rank higher than shorter ones.